# WCF Rest Service with optional client certificate

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl, client-certificates

Is it possible to have an WCF Rest Webservice which excepts SSL Client Certificates and have the IIS SSL Setting to **not** set to "require SSL" and to anly "accept" client certificates and not "require" them?

I have the following config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RestServiceBehaviour" name="PM.WCF.Service.PmRestService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="PM.WCF.Service.IPmRestService"  />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
             sendTimeout="10:15:00"
             openTimeout="10:15:00"
             receiveTimeout="10:15:00"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="StreamedRequest">

      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

My problem is the following line:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
```

If i use this setting and IIS configured to accept, but not require client certificates, I get the following error:

> The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'SslNegotiateCert'.

Sadly setting

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
```

Does not work either. I'm pretty sure the browser/client does send it's certificate, but `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.IsAuthenticated` is `False`.

Is there any other way then to have two IIS Websites, one configured to require SSL and client certificates and one which does not?

Even if there is no way around it. How do I debug this in Visual Studio? Because the moment I require SSL client certificates, I can't just start the webservice. Visual Studio tries to access `http://localhost/Foo.WCF.Service/debugattach.aspx` and fails because of the missing client certificate.

Comment: You should debug using Local IIS, you can either choose Local IIS in project settings or just attach to the IIS process with debugger. It looks you should expose service using different endpoints, one should use message security with client credentials type "Certificate", another one should use some other security type.

Comment: I do try to debug using the local IIS. But "require client cert" makes it impossible to start the project from VS. Attaching to the IIS process might work. It does not solve the need for two websites :(